# Windows / SQL Server upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2012

We are currently using Windows server 2008 R2 OS and SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and asp.net 3.5. Now we are planning to upgrade to Windows server 2012 OS and SQL SERVER 2012. Windows server 2012 is comes with IIS 8. If we upgrade from II 7  to IIS 8 do we need to make any changes to make application work. Do i need to upgrade to ASP.NET 4 or more to work my code in new servers.  what are the scenarios i need to consider when i upgrade SQL SERVER 2008 to SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: "do we need to make any changes to make application work?" - Depends on the application.  "Do i need to upgrade to ASP.NET 4 or more to work my code in new servers." - Depends on the code.  "what are the scenarios i need to consider when i upgrade SQL SERVER 2008 to SQL SERVER 2012." - This is a really broad question can you reduce the scope by chance?

Comment: I am looking for When we are upgrading to sql 2012 .. what kind of common issues we get. like invalid dataytypes, server configurations etc

Comment: Edit question....

Answer (score 0):

Database Upgrade Migration could be a complex scenario. But you can verify your basic workload with the new Database Experimentation Assistant from Microsoft.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dea/database-experimentation-assistant-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Give it a try! You first have to create a trace of your normal workload. Then you can replay this to a database on your new installed server with sql server 2012 and see what problems are have to be solved.

Regards,
Björn